# Who is the man in the ending?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the ending after the credits

> A man (the subtitles say "Stargazer") and a boy star into the sky discussing "The Shepard" (which took place a while ago). The scenery/sky seem to be the same planet where the Normandy crashed.

Who is this man and child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In real life, it's [Buzz Aldrin](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004696/).  In game:

> I think that's supposed to be ambiguous.  Some people think it is supposed to be Joker, but there's no official confirmation on that.

Comment: It's not Joker - the old man appears in the ending where the reapers win *(which you get by shooting at the boy)*.  In that ending, the old man and the child are supposed to be part of the next cycle, and they learned about Shepard from Liara's holo-documents *(at least, in my ending - it might be different if Liara doesn't survive)*.