# Is there a post-credits scene?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The epic conclusion to an space opera trilogy like Mass Effect 3 deserves an epic [post-credits scene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-credits_scene) (also known as a "[stinger](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheStinger)").

Does this game follow the pattern of games like Halo, Metroid Prime, System Shock 2, and EarthBound and reward you for waiting through the ending credits with a short clip? Obviously, this scene wouldn't suggest a sequel, but I could imagine some sort of [big reveal](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheReveal) or the answer to a [driving question](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DrivingQuestion).

**Is there a post-credits scene in Mass Effect 3? If so, what does it show?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Who is the man in the ending?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/55982/13314)

Comment: As a note, you don't need to actually wait through the credits. Pressing escape and then skipping them will still yield the scene.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. The scene is a conversation between a man and a child, who just finished telling the child the story of commander shepard. This scene is identical for all players, and doesn't appear to reveal anything of any importance.